# Search Crawl exception

Tags: service-application

During full crawl(SP 2010), we received lot of errors as " Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904" .

Can you tel me what is Root Cause for this error and how to fix.

Comment: What is the specific error that appears in your Event log or LOGS folder when this happens?

Comment: The error writted in Central Admin crwal log section during full crwal.

Comment: That is where you are seeing the error, yes.  However if you go to the server that was being crawled and look in the event log or in the LOGS folder, you should see more details

Comment: The log is captured from crwal log section in Central admin(event log/trace log couldnot found)

Answer (score 1):

Robert,
The error your sent is a very generic error and it will not help in debugging.

You may want to check if your Crawl account has appropriate permission to read the SharePoint contents.

Please turn on Verbose logging and see if you get any specific error on ULS Logs.

You can also check event log of Application Server and Database server to see if you have any error over there.

Regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

0x80131904 is SQLException which means that something went wrong when SharePoint talked to the SQL server.
This can be almost anything: Authentication error, running out of space, ...

To get the more informational error message you have to look in the Windows Event Logs using eventvwr.msc or in the ULS log files which usually are store in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS", but this may have been changed on your servers to verify the location look in http://CENTRALADMINURL:PORT/_admin/metrics.aspx

The best tool for looking at the ULS files is [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer)